# Multipath Problem

Tags: server, multipath

When I run multipath -ll, only mpatha appears but not mpathb.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output, instead copy the text from the terminal and paste it into your question, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WWID for mpathb does not match:

```
0012c8sa VS 0012c85a
```